# Django allow only a one time form submission and create and save variable

Tags: python, django

I've various probem with my code:

1. I'd like my user to be able to complete ony one time my form and then when they try to access again the page to receive the success message alert and not the form anymore. How can I achieve this?
2. When the form is submitted I get two successufull alert msg and I'd like to have just one
3. test_date field doesn't appear in my database at all.
4. I'd like to calculate the age and not making the person input that and also to create and save in my databese a code based on the input user, but I'm keeing getting an error so I # that part of the code. Is it possible?
   Thank you alll!

model

```
class UserBio(models.Model):     
   name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
   birthdate = models.DateField()  
   age = models.CharField(max_length=2)
   phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
   test_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)  
   height = models.CharField(max_length=3)
   weight = models.CharField(max_length=3)
   id = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

form

```
class UserBio(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = UserBio
       fields = (name', 'phone', 'height', 'weight')
```

views

```
def add_bio(request):
   if request.method == "POST":
       form = UserBio(request.POST)        
       if form.is_valid():            
           #age = datetime.now().year - self.birthdate.year
           #id = self.name + '_' self.height + '/' + self.weight + '_' self.phone             
           form.save()
           messages.success(request, 'Form submission successful')            
   else:
       form = UserBio()
   return render(request, 'accounts/profile/add_information.html', {'form': form})
```

html

```
{% extends 'layouts/default/page.html' %}

{% load bootstrap4 %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}

{% if messages %}
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
   {% for message in messages %}
   <h4 class="alert-heading">Well done!</h4>
    <p>----------------</p>
   <hr>
    <p class="mb-0">--------</p>
   </div>
   {% endfor %}
</ul>



{% else %}

   <form action="" method=POST> 
       {% csrf_token %}

       {% bootstrap_form form %}
       <br/>
       <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
   

{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

**EDIT:** this are the error I'm getting when I try to calcualate age (are the same for when I try to write the code):
`name 'self' is not defined`  and when i try to remove self  `name 'birthdate' is not defined`

Comment: Don't ask _multiple_ questions in one post, focus on only _one_. See [Why isn't it good to ask multiple questions and answers in one question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371614/why-isnt-it-good-to-ask-multiple-questions-and-answers-in-one-question)

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to [redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)  to a home page or a success page after a successful form submission. something like

   ```
   return redirect( 'myapp:homepage' )
   ```
2. Am guessing 1 will fix this as well
3. `auto_now_add` makes it a field that cannot be supplied by the user. You might want to remove that from the model, and supply a default of the current time to your form
4. Pass, you need to show us the error.

Comment: Thank you. About the first issue I added the code you suggest but when I go back to the page the form is still there and ready to be compiled. 
and about the error django gives me I edited my question. Thank again